# Why doesn't java.lang.Enum::valueOf check for the null name first?

Tags: java, enums

I have checked the source code for [`java.lang.Enum`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Enum.java) and the method `T valueOf(Class<T> enumType, String name)` beginning on line 232 (the implementation in both [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) and [java-11](/questions/tagged/java-11) seems equal; [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Enum.java) is the source for Java 8).

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> T valueOf(Class<T> enumType, String name) {
    T result = enumType.enumConstantDirectory().get(name);
    if (result != null)
        return result;
    if (name == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("Name is null");
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "No enum constant " + enumType.getCanonicalName() + "." + name);
}
```

What is the reason the null check for `name` happens **after** finding the enumeration by name in the `Map` get using `enumConstantDirectory()`? As far as I know, one cannot define a `null` enum; therefore the following call makes no sense:

```
MyEnum myEnum = Enum.valueOf(MyEnum.class, null);     // The NPE should be thrown
```

Although the `HashMap` implementation allows `null` as a key, I would expect the implementation would check for `null` before iterating the `Map`. What is the reason for this implementation and is there a case where searching for the `null` key before comparing `name == null` makes sense?

Comment: Maybe so that the most frequent path happens first.

Comment: I think this is a good question. Without knowing it, my assumption is that this part was implemented afterwards to make the API 'better'. From my oppinion there is no rease why this check is doing afterwards.

Comment: It's an interesting question, though I don't think fits SO because we are not the authors, and we can only guess, not give an authoritative answer. My guess: They wanted to give precedence to the exception that is thrown if the class is not a real Enum class. That is, if both arguments are incorrect, you want to throw an exception for the *first* argument *first*, and only if it's legal, throw an exception for the *second* argument.

Comment: Maybe to make faster the happy case (generally that will be used most), especially when the previous operation don't make any problem with null value

Answer (score 11, accepted):

99.999+% of calls to that method will be valid enum names. Passing a null name is always a blunder and is not the case that you want to optimize for. So moving the null check three lines down means that the check will be skipped in the common case that the enum name is valid. It doesn't change the result; it's just a tiny optimization.